# cache methods not working in Spark 1.3.0

Tags: python, caching, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I'm having problems with cache() a data frame in Spark 1.3.0 (and 1.4.0).

According to the documentation:
http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.HiveContext

No matter if I use any of the following methods:
cache() -- Persist with the default storage level (MEMORY_ONLY_SER).
cacheTable(tableName) -- Caches the specified table in-memory.

The method runs without bombing out, however when I go to perform subsequent actions on my frame or table in Spark it gives me this error message.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-7197055e2b30> in <module>()
      1 frame.show(1)
      2 frame.cache()
----> 3 frame.show(1)

/home/user/Documents/spark/python/pyspark/sql/dataframe.pyc in show(self, n)
    271         5   Bob
    272         """
--> 273         print self._jdf.showString(n).encode('utf8', 'ignore')
    274 
    275     def __repr__(self):

/home/user/Documents/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.8.2.1-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
    536         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
    537         return_value = get_return_value(answer, self.gateway_client,
--> 538                 self.target_id, self.name)
    539 
    540         for temp_arg in temp_args:

/home/user/Documents/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.8.2.1-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    298                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    299                     'An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n'.
--> 300                     format(target_id, '.', name), value)
    301             else:
    302                 raise Py4JError(

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o24.showString.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 4.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 4.0 (TID 6, localhost): java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.MutableAny cannot be cast to org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.MutableInt
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.SpecificMutableRow.getInt(SpecificMutableRow.scala:248)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.columnar.IntColumnStats.gatherStats(ColumnStats.scala:208)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.columnar.NullableColumnBuilder$class.appendFrom(NullableColumnBuilder.scala:56)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.columnar.NativeColumnBuilder.org$apache$spark$sql$columnar$compression$CompressibleColumnBuilder$$super$appendFrom(ColumnBuilder.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.columnar.compression.CompressibleColumnBuilder$class.appendFrom(CompressibleColumnBuilder.scala:78)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.columnar.NativeColumnBuilder.appendFrom(ColumnBuilder.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.columnar.InMemoryRelation$$anonfun$3$$anon$1.next(InMemoryColumnarTableScan.scala:141)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.columnar.InMemoryRelation$$anonfun$3$$anon$1.next(InMemoryColumnarTableScan.scala:117)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.MemoryStore.unrollSafely(MemoryStore.scala:277)
    at org.apache.spark.CacheManager.putInBlockManager(CacheManager.scala:172)
    at org.apache.spark.CacheManager.getOrCompute(CacheManager.scala:79)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:242)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:277)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:244)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:277)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:244)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:61)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:210)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1239)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1230)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1229)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1229)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:700)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:700)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:236)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:700)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1423)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1384)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: A few more things: I can't post my data here, but this is a simple example when I run "frame.show(1)" it works then I want to cache the frame and run "frame.cache()" that doesn't give me an error, rather when I go to perform a subsequent action it does "frame.show(1)"

Comment: Can you post your code? Also, cache is lazy, thus why you would only see it in the show method.

Comment: I've tried to create a sample set of data for you with real code to reproduce the problem, the thing is that works fine! I'm only encountering an issue when I pull the data from a HIVE table, bring it back into a Spark DataFrame, then run cache() and this has to be on my original source data stored in HIVE. If I take this same data, save it to another HIVE table, or a parquet file, then reload it back into a Spark frame and call cache() on it, then it works fine, no errors... strange...

Comment: Could you find a solution? I have the same problem.